# How to transform and merge multiple xml files into a single one

Tags: xml, xslt

I want your help to transform some XML to a new one using XSLT. I have the code of selecting multiple XMLs and applying on them the XSLT.

My problem is with the XSLT where I want to convert those shop1.xml shop2xml .. to allshops.xml. It is an easy task for someone who knows how to work with XSLT because there only 2-3 changes.

Below you can find the structures for better understanding. Thank you very much.

**shop1.xml**

```
<shop>
    <products>
        <product id="189">
            <title></title>
            <description></description>
            <price></price>
            <image></image>
            <url></url>
            <category id="61"></category>
        </product>
    </products>
</shop>
```

**shop2.xml**

```
<shop>
    <products>    
        <product id="182">
            <title></title>
            <description></description>
            <price></price>
            <image></image>
            <url></url>
            <category id="62"></category>
        </product>
    </products>
</shop>
```

**shop3.xml** //this one has directly products as root and id might be already present

```
<products>
    <product>
        <id>123</id>
        <title></title>
        <description></description>
        <price></price>
        <image></image>
        <url></url>
        <category id="62"></category>
    </product>    
</products>
```

**paths.xml** it is used from the php code to get multiple xml files

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<files>
    <file>shop1.xml</file>
    <file>shop2.xml</file>
    <file>shop3.xml</file>
</files>
```

**allshops.xml**

```
<products> //removed the store,shop and products stays as root
    <product>
        <id>the product's attribute id</id> //new element, with value the product id=""
        <title></title>
        <description></description>
        <price></price>
        <image></image>
        <url></url>
        <category></category> //removed the attribute id
        <shopid></shopid> //new element, will be blank for now
    </product>
    <product>
    </product>
    .
    .
    .
</products>
```

Comment: It would be better to load all files using `document()` XSLT 1.0 function. In this way, you will be able to correctly include the contents inside a single `products`root and also populate the `shopid` with the current file name.

Comment: Hi there. I am really interested in this solution if you are wklling to reply.

Comment: See my answer. I've kept the transform general so that it will include other nodes eventually not included in your input samples. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As requested, here a pure XSLT solution which merges the external files using the `document()` XSLT 1.0 function.

Note:

- the input to this transform is `paths.xml`.
- the transform include the well known [**Identity Transformation**](https://raw.github.com/gist/972175/b189899bb7701dde95a3cba04ced83356e738968/identity-transform.xsl).

---

[XSLT 1.0]

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:include href="identity.xsl"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <products>
            <xsl:for-each select="file">
                <xsl:apply-templates 
                    select="document(.)/*//product">
                    <xsl:with-param name="file" select="."/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </products>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="product">
        <xsl:param name="file"/>
        <xsl:copy>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>

            <xsl:if test="not(id)">
                <id><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></id>
            </xsl:if>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>

            <shopid><xsl:value-of select="$file"/></shopid>

        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="category/@id
        | product/@id"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied on `paths.xml` file provided in the question, produces:

```
<products>
   <product>
      <id>189</id>
      <title/>
      <description/>
      <price/>
      <image/>
      <url/>
      <category/>
      <shopid>shop1.xml</shopid>
   </product>
   <product>
      <id>1418</id>
      <title/>
      <description/>
      <price/>
      <image/>
      <url/>
      <category/>
      <shopid>shop1.xml</shopid>
   </product>
   <product>
      <id>182</id>
      <title/>
      <description/>
      <price/>
      <image/>
      <url/>
      <category/>
      <shopid>shop2.xml</shopid>
   </product>
   <product>
      <id>118</id>
      <title/>
      <description/>
      <price/>
      <image/>
      <url/>
      <category/>
      <shopid>shop2.xml</shopid>
   </product>
</products>
```

Comment: @Nikolai, I'm sorry for `category`, I misunderstood your question. The edited answer now fixes it. For the second question, you mean that some of your feeds have directly `products` as root element? It would be better if you expand your original question adding this new information and making it clear as much as possible. I will answer asap.

Comment: @Nikolai, anyway, I've generalized the answer to manage other feeds with different root element.

Comment: Oh sorry, I checked again one of my feeds. I saw that some of the feeds are not like `<product id="123">` but `<product><id>123></id>...</product>` that's why there is an extra `</id>` below `<product>` on the transformed XML. So if we have an if clause, that checks if there is a `<product id="123">` then create the `<id>123</id>` else if is `<product>` do not create it but continue with the next element.

Comment: Conditionally if check added. Also edited the XML in the question. Cheers

Comment: When you are ok, you might also want to remove all these comments :), being the question already edited accordingly and the full post enough understandable.

Comment: The link to the identity transformation is broken. This is why you should provide information explicitly, not link to it.

Comment: @JohnSmith ok, but in this case, you can easily search for Identity Transformation, really common subject, not really any link necessary.